# In Romans 3:1-8, what is God being faithful towards?

Tags: exegesis, bible, romans

> Then what advantage has the Jew? Or what is the value of circumcision? Much, in every way. For in the first place the Jews were entrusted with the oracles of God. What if some were unfaithful? Will their faithlessness nullify the faithfulness of God?
>   By no means! Although everyone is a liar, let God be proved true, as it is written,
>   “So that you may be justified in your words,
>   and prevail in your judging.”
>   But if our injustice serves to confirm the justice of God, what should we say? That God is unjust to inflict wrath on us? (I speak in a human way.) By no means! For then how could God judge the world? But if through my falsehood God’s truthfulness abounds to his glory, why am I still being condemned as a sinner? And why not say (as some people slander us by saying that we say), “Let us do evil so that good may come”? Their condemnation is deserved! (Romans 3:1-8, NRSV)

This passage tells us that although some Jews were unfaithful, their faithlessness does not nullify the faithfulness of God. What does it mean for God to remain faithful? Faithful towards what?

Also, in

> So that you may be justified in your words,
>   and prevail in your judging.

Which words and which judging is referred to?

Thank you, brothers and sisters!

Comment: Regarding the second question, this is more complicated because it’s a quotation from Psalm 51 (LXX 50). See also, on Hermeneutics.SE: [Who is being judged in Romans 3:4?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/9270/3555)

Answer (score 2):

The unfaithfulness of the Jews in no way hinders or nullifies God's promises to Abraham and his seed.

*"What I am saying is this: the Law, which came four hundred and thirty years later, does not invalidate a covenant previously ratified by God, so as to nullify the promise."
(Galatians 3:17 NASB)*

Despite their unfaithfulness, God has confirmed and fulfilled the promises made to Abraham by sending Jesus, the promised offspring of Abraham (Romans 15:8) so that what was promised might be given to those who believe (Galatians 3:22), not to those who work the works of the law.  Failure to keep the law does not negate God's faithfulness to his promise--the word of his oath--given to Abraham and his offspring.

Answer (score 1):

**In Romans 3:1-8, what is God being faithful towards?**

The faithfulness of God is more about his constancy that his word is trustworthy and his promises absolute.

Even Einstein caught a part of this when he said that he believed in the God of Spinoza that made himself manifest in the harmony of nature.

**Which words and which judging is referred to?**

> Romans 3:4  God forbid: yea, let God be true, but every man a liar; as
>   it is written, That thou mightest be justified in thy sayings, and
>   mightest overcome when thou art judged. - KJV
>
> Romans 3:4  By no means! Let God be found true though every human
>   being is false and a liar, as it is written, That You may be justified
>   and shown to be upright in what You say, and prevail when You are
>   judged [by sinful men]. - Amplified

Alternative translations can sometimes add a bit of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

He's being faithful to Himself as the God who cannot lie (Titus 1:2) and who has magnified His Word above His name (Psalm 138:2).